# Is there method like toHTML from String?

Tags: android, parsing

I am parsing email contents and displaying them in android webview. The problem is when the text is like:

```
 cat
 dog
 123      456
```

Creating html for webview:

```
result = (String) "<html><body>"+clearTextPart.getContent()+"</body></html>";
webView.loadData(content,"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

I want the same output but the output in webview is **"catdog123456"**. I know that problem is HTML (it ignores what spaces).

i wonder if there is some parser already implemented or i have to write my own. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `<pre></pre>` tags to preserve space/lines.

Alternatively, use CSS:

```
body { white-space: pre; }
```

Replacing `body` with whatever container your data is in.

Or even inline the style:

```
<html><body style="white-space: pre;">(your data here)</body></html>
```

Comment: thnx :) this works fine :) and is there something that you would recomend for new line as well ? :)

Comment: @MatejSpili: I've just tested the inlined version and it works for both whitespace and newlines.  Please mark the answer as accepted if it also works for you.

Comment: i will mark :) dont worry :) but it isnt working for me with inline for new line :/ can u paste code with newline as well ? :)

Comment: `result = (String) "<html><body style=\"white-space:pre;\">"+clearTextPart.getContent()+"</body></html>";
webView.loadData(content,"text/html", "UTF-8");`

Comment: also try `result = (String) "<html><body><pre>"+clearTextPart.getContent()+"</pre></body></html>"; webView.loadData(content,"text/html", "UTF-8");`

Comment: If neither of those work, then your browser is defective and not standards-compliant - in which case, file a bug report.

Comment: i solved it :) the problem was not in HTML but with webview ... correct method for putting html content is 'webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", "UTF-8");'